# Data driven testing from excel using groovy scripting in soapui free version

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I am getting the below error logs when am trying to do the parameterization using groovy with the follow code:

```
package org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser; 
import java.io.*; 
import jxl.*; 
import org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer; 

Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:\\SOAPUI\\ConversionRate.xls") 
Sheet sheet1 = workbook.getSheet("DataDriven"); 
row = sheet1.getRow(); col = sheet1.getColumns(); 
log.info "Row Count =" +row 
log.info "Column Count =" +col 
for(i=1;i<row;i++) { 
    for(j=0;;j<col;j++) { 
       def celsius = testRunner.tetCase.getStepByName("Properties") 
       cell var = sheet1.getCell(i,j) 
       log.info var.getContents() 
    } 
}
```

Note: I have placed all the jars along with jxl in bin/ext folder.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
startup failed: Script7.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.company.ui.test.SoapUI_T11001_StockConsSecurityCurBusiDate @ line 1, column    
                             ^
org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class com.company.ui.test.SoapUI_T11001_StockConsSecurityCurBusiDate @ line 1, column 1.
 at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:148)  
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1206)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:148)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$6.call(CompilationUnit.java:585)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:832)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:519)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:495)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:472)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:292)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:727)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.ja`enter code here`va:739)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:766)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:757)
 at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:141)
 at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:90)
 at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:148)
 at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:274)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
 1 error
```

Comment: Seems that a custom class (not jxl) related is missing `com.company.ui.test...`. Can you add the Groovy code which it's throwing this exception?

Comment: I add the code to your question, the next time try to edit your question instead of pasting it in the comments `:)`.

Comment: Some comments :). In a Groovy testStep script don't add package information; why you adding `package org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser; ` for sure this is not necessary here. In the groovy script I don't see where are you using the class which is in the cause of the error in the trace `com.company.ui.test.SoapUI_T11001_StockConsSecurityCurBusiDate`.

Comment: can u provide your contact info..mail or facebook id..need your help..pls

Comment: sorry but I don't want to provide my contact here, It's better that you provide all the missing details and we will try to help you :).

Comment: hi abciff..the below are real exceptions am getting

Comment: you're missing the last `)` to close `getWorkbook(` in the first line, this is why `Sheet` is not recognized.

Comment: I escaped from all the above errors, now facing below errors

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getRow() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: getRow(int), getRows(), getPLS(), getAt(java.lang.String), getName(), getCell(java.lang.String) error at line: 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Groovy* testStep doesn't have an autocomplete feature so sometimes it's a bit pain to deal with class methods and other typos... this is why you probably can't make your code work. So let's go I'll try to enumerate the errors:

- In SOAPUI *Groovy* testStep `package` its not necessary...
  furthermore this one is for sure not the correct one in your case:
  `package org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser;`
- There are not necessaries `import` in your code:

  ```
  // groovy add java.io.* by default
  import java.io.*
  // this is not used in your code
  import org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer
  ```
- There are also some typos; in the first line `)` is missing to close `getWorkbook(`; you don't define any type for `row` and `col` variables; there is an extra `;` in your loop `for(j=0;;j<cols;j++)`.
- To get the total number of rows and columns with *jxl* use [`Sheet.getColumns()`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Sheet.html#getColumns()) and [`Sheet.getRows()`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Sheet.html#getRows()) instead.
- [`jxl.Cell`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Cell.html)class start with upper case ([*Java* convention for class name is CamelCase](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#15411))
- [`Sheet.getCell(int column, int row)`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Sheet.html#getCell(int,%20int)) expect `column` position as a first argument, and `row` as second not the other way around.

So your code corrected could be:

```
import jxl.*

Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:/SOAPUI/ConversionRate.xls"))
Sheet sheet1 = workbook.getSheet("DataDriven")
def rows = sheet1.getRows()
def cols = sheet1.getColumns()
log.info "Row Count =" + rows 
log.info "Column Count =" + cols 
for(i=1;i<rows;i++) { 
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++) { 
       Cell cell = sheet1.getCell(j,i) 
       log.info cell.getContents() 
    } 
}
```

Note that I don't test it but I suppose that once is corrected must works, go ahead an try it.

Comment: hi...I tried with your corrected code..Still am getting the error logs

Comment: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script8.groovy: 13: unable to resolve class Workbook @ line 13, column 18. Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:\\SOAPUI\\ConversionRate.xls")) ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class Workbook @ line 13, column 18. at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:146)

Comment: @AlaguPandi It's hard to help someone who don't try to understand what is doing. `jxl.Workbook` class exists so if you add the jar in *SOAPUI\bin\ext*  this class must be available. Furthermore your error is showing the problem in line 13... how is this possible when `Workbook`in the code snippet is in line 3? You're not executing the answer snippet you're executing a different one, isn't it?

Comment: Your correct..the problem @line 3 only...but error logs are same as above.. Also i have jxl jar in bin/ext..

Comment: @AlaguPandi finally I download `jxl-2.6.12.jar` and test the code and it works for me (note that I correct another two errors). Do you restart SOAPUI after added the jar in *bin/ext*? If not please restart it in order that SOAPUI can load the jar classes.

Comment: @aIbciff..I don't have words to thank your help..But still am facing the same issue..I have restarted the machine also..But it's not working actually..

Comment: @aIbciff. Actually i have restarted the machine since i didn't find the options to restart SoapUI.. Any options to restart pls let me know

Comment: @AlaguPandi When I said restart SOAPUI I mean to close and open again so seems that you do it correctly. What version are you using? are you sure that you copy the correct jars in the correct path? Check the soapui startup-log to see it here is something like: `[SoapUI] Adding [...\SoapUI-5.0.0\bin\ext\jxl-2.6.12.jar] to extensions classpath`

Comment: @albciff..Need your help...Do u have any scripts for reading test data from excel and running the test data in XML request file and validating the response in groovy

Comment: @AlaguPandi if finally the answer solves your problem think about [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you've another question please post a new one with all the related details (what do you want, what did you try, exceptions if applies etc) [see how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) `:)`